# The website does not load fully when scraping with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some dispensaries from weedmaps.com using Selenium and BeautifulSoup. Weedmaps was blocking me as it detected I am a bot (which in itself was pretty irritating). So I did a google search first and through that accessed the main website. Now the real irritating thing is that https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/earth. When I reach this link via clicking in Selenium I see this:
[image: Selenium picture]

However when I manually do the same clicking on chrome I see:

[image: Chrome Picture]

I am not able to understand what is causing this but I feel like it might be the way Selenium displays stuff, because google.com looks like this which it should'nt as the graphics are brutal:

[image]

Please help me. in figuring out a way to see the actual stuff so I can start scraping or at least move forward.:

My code is this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# get the ChromeDriver so that this code works on every device
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

from fake_useragent import UserAgent
user_agent = UserAgent().random
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/vaibhav2001/Downloads/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)


driver.get("https://google.com")
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='lst']")
search_bar.send_keys("weedmaps")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('lsb').click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='kCrYT']/a")[0].click()
```

Comment: Use your main chrome profile to do the scraping instead of using a blank profile

Comment: I see the same error page while manually accessing the url https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/in/earth

Comment: @TarunLalwani Can you tell me how to do so! Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB it happens sometimes. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal As we can't access the url even manually logically I'll conclude it's an invalid url, however access to this url may have zonal restrictions.